# Android: Telnet using Socket - missing last line

Tags: android, sockets, telnet, readline

I'm trying to write some MUD Client for android, and I run into problem with output from server. I can't get my app to show last line (Login prompt) in console..

```
try {
        Socket socket = new Socket("studnia.mud.pl", 4004);
        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out);
        output.println("Siema, pisze klient mudowy pod androida wiec nie bijcie że testuje na studni. :(");

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        String line="1";
        while(line!=null){
            line = input.readLine();
            Log.i("Socket", line);
        }
        socket.close();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Your code does not provide many information so try to inform us a little more in order to help you. A common problem is that you use blocking sockets. That means in order to read a next message you have to write back to the server a message. To be more specific when you read from a socket that is in blocking mode (the most commonly used at tutorials etc) you have to write something to the socket (and read it at the other side) in order to be able to read the next message and so one.

Comment: I've been sniffing packets while using windows telnet client. And I only recive one packet, without even sending any. And it contains that missing prompt as well. So I don't have to write back to receive it.

Answer (score 0):

`readLine()` does not return the login prompt line because this line is not yet complete - there is no line-termination character until the login name has been entered. In order to get the partial line with the prompt, you cannot use `readLine()`; try something like `while (input.ready()) { int c = input.read(); ... }` or `input.read(cbuf, 0, len)`.

Comment: I came across the same problem which I've been struggling some time. The solution is definitely to read the characters instead of reading lines. Telnet protocol sends the output as characters and there is no newline character at the end (I could not found a prompt character as well) which was not a solution in my case, I was parsing the output line by line and using html tags to colour the text via ANSI encoding. If anyone can find a better solution to trigger when the server can receive a message (prompt character), it would be appreciated.